# Copy array to another empty array in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to copy these three array to one empty array. And I want to check "marks" array in a for loop.

```
int[] Math={85,65,40,20}; 
int[] English={35,55,68,75}; 
int[] ICT={50,35,69,95};

int i; 
int x=1;

int[] marks; 

if (x==1) {
       marks=Math;
}
else if (x==2) {
      marks=English;
}
else if (x==3) {
      marks=ICT;
}
for (i=0; i<4; i++ )
{
// check Marks array inside a for loop
}
```

Comment: To check the values of `marks` use something like `if (marks[i] ...)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The question is not too clear.

Comment: `marks` will always be `Math` since `x` is always `1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to initialize marks array.

```
    int[] Math = {85,65,40,20}; 
    int[] English = {35,55,68,75}; 
    int[] ICT = {50,35,69,95};

    int i; 
    int x=1;

    int[] marks = new int[4];

    if (x==1) {
           marks=Math;
    }
    else if (x==2) {
          marks=English;
    }
    else if (x==3) {
          marks=ICT;
    }

    for (i=0; i<4; i++ )
    {
        System.out.print(marks[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: The question is not answerable as we don't know what the OP wants to do.  You have made an assumption that may or may not be right.  And, your "answer" is incorrect, there's no need to initialize `marks` as it will be set to refer to one of the other arrays.  The initialization you propose is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy 3 arrays using the below method. The other part of the question is not clear to me.

```
int[] Math = {85, 65, 40, 20};
    int[] English = {35, 55, 68, 75};
    int[] ICT = {50, 35, 69, 95};

    int[] marks = new int[Math.length + English.length + ICT.length]; 

    System.arraycopy(Math, 0, marks, 0, Math.length);
    System.arraycopy(English, 0, marks, Math.length, English.length);
    System.arraycopy(ICT, 0, marks,  Math.length+English.length, ICT.length);

    for (int x = 0; x < marks.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(marks[x]);
    }
```